# Why does passing in a single subtype for a varargs in an implicit def give a type mismatch?

Tags: scala, implicit

Given the following code snippet

```
sealed trait A
case class B() extends A

object Creator {
  def apply(plus: Plus) = plus()
}

sealed trait Plus {
  def apply(): Int
}

object Plus {
  implicit def supersWrapper(supers: A*) = // Changing this to just A works
    new Plus {
      def apply(): Int = 5
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
scala> Creator(B())
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
found   : B
required: Plus
Creator(B())
```

If I change the type of supers to A, I get the following

```
scala> Creator(B())
res9: Int = 5
```

Why am I getting the behavior above? I know I can just define two implicit defs for A and A* but I would like to know why I need to do this.

Comment: Implicit argument with varargs seems pretty strange to me. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301449/implicit-def-with-varargs.

Comment: You say you can "just define two implicit defs for A and A*". I can't seem to make a varvargs converter work. Can you actually invoke an implicit conversion via a varargs parameter?

Comment: @jwvh Oh whoops I mean A and List[A] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit conversion functions can only be applied to one parameter, always. Hence `implicit def supersWrapper(supers: A*)` does not make sense, but scalac does not generate a warning for that.